# Extracting matched using fuzzysearch

Tags: python-3.7, fuzzy-search

I am trying to extract the parameters in fuzzysearch

https://github.com/taleinat/fuzzysearch

The result I get looks like this:

```
>>> from fuzzysearch import find_near_matches
# search for 'PATTERN' with a maximum Levenshtein Distance of 1
>>> find_near_matches('PATTERN', '---PATERN---', max_l_dist=1)
[Match(start=3, end=9, dist=1, matched="PATERN")]
```

How do I extract 'matched' and 'dist' from the resulting list?
I can't seem to index the output

Comment: Supposing your list of near matches is `near_matches`, do `near_matches[0].dist` and `near_matches[0].matched` not work?

Comment: Oh it worked! Thank you @Kraigolas

Answer (score 0):

To extract distance - `near_matches[0].dist`. To extract pattern - `near_matches[0].matched`